# Passing data around java classes

Tags: java, android, rss

Java noob here! I'm struggling to put the finishing touch to an Android app that I'm writing. Essentially, it's an RSS reader. An async task fetches an RSS feed. It's then parsed, and the final bit I want to do is update a ListView element of an activity with the parsed RSS.

Because the fetcher tast is asynchronous, it's in its own class, so it can't update the UI directly (I believe).

My onPostExecute declaration is:

```
public class getNews extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    String server_response;  
    // url fetch stuff is in here
}

protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            FullscreenActivity.updateNews(server_response)

        }
```

The FullscreenActivity.java class receives the server_response and parses it fine:

```
public static void updateNews(String newsXML) {

// stuff goes on here, and I end up with a string array called headlines that
// contains the news headlines

}
```

My problem comes when I try to update the ListView. If I try to do it in updateNews like this

```
ListView m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewRight);
```

I get a red-wiggly under findViewById that says Non-static method...cannot be referenced from a static context.

If I make updateNews() non-static, I get a red-wiggly under updateNews in my onPostExecute routine saying the same thing.

So, my question is, what mix of flavours do I need in my subroutine declarations that will allow me to get the XML out of my async receiver, through a parser, and into my ListView?

I'm totally confused by statics, privates, publics etc. Even after trying to read about them I'm none the wiser!

I can post the entire project to Github if it's any help. I'm sure it's not exactly a shining example of how java should look!

Thanks in advance,
Iain

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help and explanations. Following this, I've got my code working by adding a couple of lines to my activity class. I'll explain below. Not enough characters available here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because the fetcher tast is asynchronous, it's in its own class, so it can't update the UI directly (I believe).

This depends on exactly what you think "directly" means. It is true that the Android framework will crash your app if you try to update a `View` from any thread other than the UI thread (aka the main thread). But `AsyncTask` runs e.g. `onPostExecute()` on the UI thread so it's perfectly valid to update views inside this method.

You say that your task is "in its own class", so by default you won't have access to any views to update... but you could set things up so that you *do* have this access.

> I'm totally confused by statics, privates, publics etc. Even after trying to read about them I'm none the wiser!

First let's talk about `private` and `public`. These are known as *access level modifiers* and you can read about them in great detail here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

However, a quick summary should be sufficient. If something is `private`, that means the only objects that can use it are ones of the same type. If something is `public`, that means anyone can use it.

`static` is different. This keyword defines whether the variable or method you've applied it to is an "instance" member (something without the `static` keyword) or a "class" member (something with the `static` keyword). Again, you can read about it in detail here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

And, again, a quick summary should suffice. If something is `static`, that means it is **shared by all instances of that class**. In other words, it's related to the "idea" of that class, not a specific instance of that class. Otherwise, the variable or method is related only to a specific instance of the class.

Going back to your actual example, we can talk about this method:

```
public static void updateNews(String newsXML) {
    ...
}
```

This method is `static`, which means it's shared by all instances of `FullscreenActivity`. It is `public`, which means anyone can use it. So your `AsyncTask` can easily call into it by writing

```
FullscreenActivity.updateNews(server_response);
```

But when you're working with activities in Android, you are generally concerned with the behavior of a specific instance of an activity, and not with the general idea of your activity. That is, you want to update the screen of the activity that's up and running on your user's phone, not all `FullscreenActivity` instances that might ever exist!

So you should make this method non-static:

```
public void updateNews(String newsXML) {
    ...
}
```

Now that this method is non-static, you need a `FullscreenActivity` instance to call it on. Something that will let you write this:

```
activity.updateNews(server_response);
```

One easy way to do this is to pass your activity to your `AsyncTask`'s constructor.

```
public class GetNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private FullscreenActivity activity;

    public GetNews(FullscreenActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    ...

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        activity.updateNews(server_response);
    }
}
```

Now, when you create your `GetNews` instance, rather than writing `new GetNews()` you can write `new GetNews(this)` (assuming you're inside `FullscreenActivity` when you run this code).

Answer (score 0):

Well worst thing that

```
public static void updateNews(String newsXML) {
    //dunno what do you want to do here    
}
```

Will not work since static method is related with **class**, but not with **instance**.

First thing you can do - pass `Activity` instance to your `AsyncTask`.

```
public class GetNews extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    String server_response;  
    FullscreenActivity activity;
    public GetNews(FullscreenActivityactivity) {
         this.activity = activity;
    }
}
```

Make your

```
public static void updateNews(String newsXML) {}
```

non `static`

```
public void updateNews(String newsXML) {}
```

So you can do what you want like that

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (activity != null)
                 activity.updateNews(server_response)
}
```

**Update:**

about

```
ListView m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewRight);
```

why not to make `m_listview` as field of your `Activity` class and instantiate it in `onCreate` method?

```
public class FullscreenActivityactivity extends Activity {
    private ListView m_listview;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewRight);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

findViewById is a non-static method.  This means it needs to be called on an instance of Activity, and can not be called in a static method.

In general having static methods to update your Activity won't work (and the ways you can hack it to make it work are considered bad ideas and generally lead to memory leaks).  Your AsyncTask should either be a inner class of your activity (in which case it can call a non-static update function), or you should pass it an interface to call when finished (and your activity should pass it an interface which calls updateList).

Comment: Presumably you mean "inner class" and not "subclass".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for your help and explanations. Following this, I've got my code working by adding a couple of lines to my activity class:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ListView m_listview;
    public static Activity myThis;
```

Then in onCreate, I've added:

```
m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewRight);
myThis = this; // seems messy?
```

Which lets me update my ListView when I need to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(myThis, R.layout.listview_row_layout, R.id.firstLine, headlines);
m_listview.setAdapter(adapter);`
```

I'll continue to tinker with it. I've been wanting to learn Java and Android development for years, and now I've got a project to do so.

My background is a lot of older languages (basic, mostly) and some scripting languages such as Perl. Still finding Java to be a strange beast, but hoping to get better despite my years! old_dog.new_tricks.teach(); :)